# wildcard in array

Tags: arrays, powershell

How can I use the 1709 as a wildcard? The value 1709 is stored in an array as `$MoveItem.Version`, but I can't figure out how do a `-like`, when the value comes from an array, as I can't put in a wildcard `*`. I also tried to do a match.

The file name looks like this: `REFW10-X86-1709_01-12-2017.wim`.

The below code works fine, but I would like to automate it, so everything comes from the array. Is that possible?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $OSPathTemp  -Recurse | Where {
    ($_.Name -eq $MoveItem.File) -and
    ($_.Name -like "*1709*")
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

`$MoveItem.Version` contains `1607,1706,1709`. I would like to choose only the one with 1709. The final output should look like this:

```
foreach ($MoveItem in $MoveItems) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $OSPathTemp -Recurse | Where {
        ($_.Name -eq $MoveItem.File) -and
        ($_.Name -like $MoveItem.Version)
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
}
```

The Array looks like this:

```
$MoveItem = @(

[pscustomobject]@{File="REFW10-X86-1709_01-12-2017.wim";Version=1709}
[pscustomobject]@{File="REFW10-X86-1706_01-12-2017.wim";Version=1706}

)
```

Comment: I'm going to be honest with you. Maybe it is too early or something but I can't understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I can't test it, but  `($_.Name -like "*$($MoveItem.Version)*")` should do what you want.

Comment: @JamesC. That's not going to work with an array.  `$x = 1,2,3,4; "*$($x)*"` will output `*1 2 3 4*`.

Comment: So, as I understand it, you have an array, `$MoveItem.Versions`, that looks like `1709,1710,1711,...`.  And you want to operate on files `REFW10-X86-1709_01-12-2017.wim`, `REFW10-X86-1710_01-12-2017.wim`, `REFW10-X86-1711_01-12-2017.wim`,`...`?

Comment: I'd read it as `$MoveItem.Version` contains just the value `1709` that they want to use with wildcard... further clarification needed on this I guess.

Comment: @BaconBits Yes exactly

Comment: How do you know which version you want?  Do you always want the most recent version, or is that a decision that must be made at runtime?

Comment: @user7490700 Put the code snippet James C. suggested in his first comment in your second code sample, and the code should do exactly what you want.

Comment: The version comes from the filenane, so when the filename includes *1709*, i want the full path for that filename..

Comment: What's the point of looking for a specific version if you're comparing the name exactly? `$_.Name -eq $MoveItem.File`

Comment: I now have no idea what the bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve even is!

Comment: @JamesC. You pointed me in the right direction, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a hash table (or similar) named `$MoveItem` that has a `.File` property that is a filename, and you have a `.Versions` property that's a string array?

Test name: `REFW10-X86-1709_01-12-2017.wim`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $OSPathTemp -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        If ($_.Name -match '-\d{4}_') { $Version = $Matches[0] }

        If ($Version -in $MoveItem.Versions -and
            $_.Name -eq $MoveItem.File) { $_.FullName }
    }
```